# How can I programmatically create JMS topics and queues in HornetQ?

Tags: hornetq

How can I programmatically create JMS topics and queues with HornetQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/user-manual/en/html/management.html

and if you read the chapter about how core addresses are translated into JMS objects:

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/api/org/hornetq/api/core/client/ClientSession.html#createQueue(org.hornetq.api.core.SimpleString,%20org.hornetq.api.core.SimpleString,%20boolean)

And you could also use just the core api if you like.

Comment: Thanks, in this case, our problem is creating JMS messages.
Core messages are wonderfully easy to create, but JMS... :)

Comment: Remember, JMS Queues are translated as core queues with jms.queue. on its prefix. and topics are also core queues with some composed name of the topic address name, client-id and subscription name.